# Powershell - Masking a line with secure string causing

Tags: powershell

To log into something, I have to enter a username on page1, password on page2, then click submit on page3. To make it easier I wrote a PS script. I double checked it by hard-coding the password, and it was successful.

But not wanting to hard-code the password I used the added `$pass` and how to read it. But now I get invalid password when I run the script.

I wanted to use `Get-Credentials`, but didn't know how to just pass in the username or password on their specific pages.

I would appreciate any advice to help me in the right direction towards my goal.

```
$pass = Read-Host 'd\P What is your password?' -AsSecureString
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto(
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass))
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$URL = 'https://website/'
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.Navigate($URL)
While ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000} 
$ie.Document.getElementById('DATA').value = "P0523586"
$Submit = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('Input') | ? {$_.Type -eq "Submit"}
$Submit.click()
While ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000} 
$ie.Document.getElementById('DATA').value = "$pass"
$Submit = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('Input') | ? {$_.Type -eq "Submit"}
$Submit.click()
While ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000} 
$Submit = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('Input') | ? {$_.Type -eq "Submit"}
$Submit.click()
```

Comment: Did you echo the decoded `$pass` to make sure it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Credential` is a good way to go about this as you aren't storing anything that should be kept secure in the script.

It's easiest to assign the Object returned from `Get-Credentials` to a variable:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
```

You can then use `$credentials.UserName` to retrieve the username:

```
PS> $credentials.UserName
myusername
```

And `$credentials.Password` to retrieve Secure Password Object

```
PS> $credentials.Password
System.Security.SecureString
```

This can be used by other PowerShell commands, but needs to be decoded (made un-secure) before it can be sent to a process that cannot accept secure password objects.

To retrieve the password in plain-text, you can use the `GetNetworkCredential` method like this:

```
PS> $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
mypassword
```

---

In your script you would add `$credentials = Get-Credential` at the start of your script, and submit the username/password to the form like this:

```
$ie.Document.getElementById('DATA').value = $credentials.UserName

$ie.Document.getElementById('DATA').value = $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. When I run this I get the credential box, to enter my data. When it enters my username into the field, it auto populates my username with a '\' infront of it, causing an access denied message. Any thoughts on how to get rid of it?

Comment: As of PowerShell v3 `Get-Credential` no longer inserts a backslash before the username when you do not specify a domain. You'll either need to update PowerShell (v1/v2 are really really old!) or use `($credentials.UserName).Substring(1)` to get the substring starting at the second letter(index 1), this method isn't great as if you run on a newer version of powershell your username will be missing it's first letter.